# Can't connect to MS SQL Server on network

Tags: sql-server

SQL server does not seem to be communicating. Port 1433 is open. SQL Configuration Manager used to turn on port 1433. SQL Management Studio used to turn on communications. "NETSTAT -an" on the server shows nothing listening on port 1433. Any ideas?
[SQL Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh0P4.jpg)

[image]

Comment: firewall allow sqlservices

Comment: By "SQL Management Studio used to turn on communications" do you mean you've enabled remote connections?

Comment: Not necessarily the port number 1433

Comment: Please send us the error message too

Comment: Did you try to desactivate TCP/IP, Apply, Reactivate TCP/IP and restart SQL Instance ?
By "can't connect to MS SQL Server on network" do you mean you can't connect with Management Studio ?

Comment: In SQL Management Studio, Properties of DB, Remote Connections checked. In SQL Configuration Manager, Protocols for DB, TCP/IP Enabled on port 1433. NETSTAT -o does not show any process on that port.